# Static IP in Ubuntu 13.10 & How to loop/run terminal commands at startup

Tags: 13.10

I need help. I want to obtain a static IP address and loop a terminal command on startup, so when the computer boots up, it launches a terminal Window that loops a command over and over again. And, I want a Static IP, I know the default gateway and mask.

Comment: why do you want to loop the terminal command? Use `/etc/network/interfaces``to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a static IP :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

add :

```
auto eth0 (eth0 is the name of my interface )
iface eth0 inet static
address (your static IP)
netmask (your netmask)
```

If you need to launch a command on login :

add it in :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

Comment: How do I tell the name of my interface? is mine the same as yours, or do I put belkin or belkin54g because that's my router name? (belkin is the company, belkin54g is the name of the router, and, do I add the command at the end of the file /etc/init.d/rc.local?) and, what if I want to add more than 1 command?

Comment: Ok. I tried that and now I can't connect, I don't have a backup file, when I tried to revert it, it said "Waiting for network configuration" upon boot.